# Facing error when formatting hdfs namenode

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have already added the required java home in hadoop-env.sh.

[image: strong text]

```
adminn@hadoop-master:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
adminn@hadoop-master:~$
```

Comment: The error says the `JAVA_HOME` you used does not exist, so prove to us that it does exist. Please share terminal output as text, not images.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, see i have run the java_home command is there any issue in the result?

Comment: That just echos a string. Doesn't prove that folder actually exists

Comment: ohh, can you suggest how i can check?

Comment: `cd` into the folder, if you can, or use `ls` to list directory content

Comment: Please post the error as *text* and not as a screenshot. Images are not text searchable